# Running Nginx while a service is running

Tags: nginx, docker

I have a server already running a docker container on port 80 (and 443). In hindsight, I was not able to foresee that I might have to deploy two subdomains on the same server. I have read that Nginx is a perfect solution for hosting multiple subdomains on the same server. Ideally something like this:

- `https://<service0>.<mydomain>.<com>/`
- `https://<service1>.<mydomain>.<com>/`

So now I will run `service1` on some unoccupied port, but my question is that both subdomains will have to be accessible on port 80 (and 443), but my `service0` docker container is already running and listening on port 80. Is it possible to put Nginx on top of it, as in listen to all traffic for subdomain `service0` and forward it to 'actual' port 80 and some other port for `service1`. I am asking this because I am not allowed to change the port of current `service0` which runs on port 80. I can stop the container for a while but nothing much.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1462449/i-have-a-domain-static-ip-address-and-many-devices-id-like-to-access-outside-m/1462491#1462491

Comment: @Daniel yeah but in my case the docker is running on port 80 already though (and I ideal won't want to change that) and so is my other container. And I want to put (on the same server) and nginx proxy as the 'supervisor'

Comment: I don't know which docker image you are using, maybe if there is a nginx instance inside, you can use that as the reverse proxy

Comment: @Daniel that's really interesting! I will try it out. So I'd simply redirect the remainder of the traffic (i.e. <service1>) to another docker on the host. I am not sure about host permissions though.

Comment: You can probably redirect to any ip from the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

First look here:[How do i Map a port to Docker or set a new one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container)

After changing your docker port to i.e. 8080 and 8081 install nginx to run on the local machine.
After this, Setup Nginx as Reverse-Proxy like:

## Host one: (into /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service0.mydomain.com)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <service0>.<mydomain>.<com>
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://10.11.12.13:8080
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_buffers 16 4k;
                    proxy_buffer_size 2k;
                    gzip on;
                    #gzip_proxied no-cache no-store private expired auth;
                    gzip_vary          on;
                    gzip_comp_level    8;
                    gzip_proxied       any;

}
```

## Host two:: (into /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service1.mydomain.com)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <service1>.<mydomain>.<com>
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://10.11.12.13:8080
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_buffers 16 4k;
                    proxy_buffer_size 2k;
                    gzip on;
                    #gzip_proxied no-cache no-store private expired auth;
                    gzip_vary          on;
                    gzip_comp_level    8;
                    gzip_proxied       any;

}
```

Where 10.11.12.13 is the IP of the maschine,

- if the docker is running on the same host replace it with 127.0.0.1
- Change the Port after proxy_pass to that you above

## Benefits:

- nginx is enabled for caching, without redirection to SSL

## Bad's?

- No auto redirect - but heres the way how

## Autoredirect (only one example)

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.domain.de;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name subdomain.domain.de;
            location / {
                    proxy_set_header        X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
                    proxy_cache_valid       200 1w;
                    proxy_pass              https://10.11.12.13:8080;
                    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
                    proxy_buffers           16 8m;
                    proxy_buffer_size       2m;
                    gzip on;
                    gzip_vary          on;
                    gzip_comp_level    9;
                    gzip_proxied       any;
}
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

## Benefits?

- Auto redirect nginx Style to SSL
- Remind that the SSL-Part has to be set by certbot
- Cache is enabled

## Bads?

- No http connection possible - but thats what we want

hope i could help you to solve your issue

Comment: OP specifically wrote the port on docker container cannot be changed.

Comment: nope, He wrote He accidently startet it without changing it, so i advised how He can do it and that should He flow